# Statically defining options for a type of a derived class

Tags: c#, .net, attributes, static-methods

I'm developing a framework where a class inheriting from an abstract class of the framework needs to be able to specify the schema for the options it can accept when it is called to DoStuff().

I started out with an abstract GetOptionsSchema() method like this:

```cs
public abstract class Widget
{
    public abstract OptionsSchema GetOptionsSchema();
    public abstract void DoStuff(Options options);
}
```

Other developers would then extend on my framework by creating custom Widget types:

```cs
public abstract class FooWidget: Widget
{
    public overide DoStuff(Options options)
    {
        //Do some FooWidget stuff
    }

    public overide OptionsSchema GetOptionsSchema()
    {
        //Return options for FooWidget
    }
}
```

This works but requires the framework to create an instance of every Widget type to determine options schema they accept, even if it has no need to actually DoStuff() with any of these types.

Ultimately, I'd like to be able to determine the options schema for a specific Widget type directly from a System.Type. I would create a custom OptionsSchema attribute, but constructing these schemas is more complicated then would make sense to do in the constructor of an attribute. It needs to happen in a method.

I've seen other frameworks solve similar problems by creating a custom attribute that identifies a static method or property by name. For example the [TestCaseSource](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/TestCaseSource-Attribute) attribute in NUnit.

Here's what this option might look like:

```cs
public abstract class Widget
{
    public abstract void DoStuff(Options options);
}

[OptionsSchemaSource(nameof(GetOptionsSchema))]
public abstract class FooWidget: Widget
{
    public overide DoStuff(Options options)
    {
        //Do some FooWidget stuff
    }

    public static OptionSchema GetOptionsSchema()
    {
        //Return options for FooWidget
    }
}
```

I like how the OptionsSchemaSource attribute makes it possible to get the options schema directly from a System.Type, but this also seem much less discoverable to other developers creating custom Widget types.

With the abstract method another Widget developer knows they must override GetOptionSchema() because their code would not compile otherwise. With the OptionsSchemaSource attribute the best I could do would be to hope people read my documentation and have the framework throw an exception at run-time if it encounters a Widget with out an OptionsSchemaSource attribute.

Is there an alternative/better/recommended approach to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pretty much already know everything of interest to judge what's the best approach.

As already mentioned, you cannot have static interfaces defined on your type, so there is no way you can ensure a new developer is *enforced* to add the attribute.

So, the two alternatives you identified are the only two I can think of.
Now, let's do a pros and cons and try to sharpen them.

#### Attribute

You can lessen the pain of ensuring devs put attributes on the classes with meaningful error messages. I would say that you should manage the discovery of the classes based exclusively on Attributes, not in inheritance.
If you manage everything with Attributes, you don't need to inherit from Widget.
This is a pro, because now everyone can inherit if it's desirable, and re-implement if it's preferred.

The con is that the implementation of discoverability will be more complex: you will need to use reflection at start up, get a `MethodInfo`, check that the method has the correct signature, give proper errors in case and invoke the method unboxing the result as needed.

Think about it: you would like a static method because you don't need to instantiate a single typed Widget instance, but actually instantiating a new Widget could very well be not a big deal.

#### Abstract class

Well, you enforce an inheritance chain over you developers, which could be ok, necessary or entirely optional (you judge), but you get a self documenting experience.

The apparent con is that at startup you need to instantiate a Widget for every derived type you discover, but that could very well be peanuts compared to assembly scanning and type checking and methodinfo discovery and method calls through reflection.
Ugly? Kind of. Inefficient? Not so much. And it's code that is invisible to your end user.

#### IMHO

I find quite a good tradeoff, when designing a framework, to put some "ugly" code *inside* the framework, if it means that every single implementation using the library is going to be even a little bit better.

All in all, if you're designing a library that you want to be flexible and discoverable, you should expect a developer to read at least a quick start guide. If they can read in 5 minutes a single bit of information (either "extend a base class" or "add a single or a couple attributes") and that single bit gives them an direction into discovering every aspect of widget registration, I would be ok: you can't really get much better than this.

My call: I would go the abstract class route with a smallish caveat. I really don't like having an enforced base class. So I would organize discovery at startup based on interface, `IWidget`, containing the `GetOptionsSchema` method and everything is needed to use the widget (which could be the `DoStuff` method, but could very well be something else). At startup you search for implementations of the interface which are not abstract, and you're good to go.

**If**, and only if, the only bit you *really* need in advance is a string or other similarly simple type, I would require an additional attribute.

```cs
[OptionsSchemaName("http://something")]
public class MyWidget : WidgetBase
{
    public overide DoStuff(Options options)
    {
        //Do some FooWidget stuff
    }

    public static OptionSchema GetOptionsSchema()
    {
        //Return options for FooWidget
    }
}
```

Then, your type discovery infrastructure can search for non-abstract `IWidget`s and throw a meaningful error right at startup like `the type MyWidget is lacking an OptionsSchemaName attribute. Every implementation of IWidget must define one. See http://mydocs for information`.

Bang! Nailed it!

Answer (score 1):

It's not currently possible to enforce the attribute at compile time; that would've been ideal for your use case. It's also not possible to have an `abstract static` method, or have a static method specified in an interface; so there is no way to ensure the method is actually there at compile time, except by enforcing an instance method via abstract class or interface (which will require an instance of the type to access).

I'd go with the attribute idea - it's not unreasonable to expect developers to read documentation; even with overriding an abstract method, the developer would need to know how to construct an `OptionSchema` in the overridden method - back to documentation!